# Cannot reference an XML string resource in Java (Android)

Tags: android, xml, string, reference

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this isn't working.  I am trying to reference a string from my strings.xml file in my Java code.  For some reason, I can reference every string within the same xml file except the two strings that I need to reference.  I don't know if I am saying this clearly, but below is my current code so I can show this better:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package bcs421.jorgeramirez.hwk.hellogoodbye;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button greetButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.greetingButton);
    Button goodbyeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goodbyeButton);
    greetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast greeting;
            Context context;
            CharSequence text = getString(R.string.greeting_toast);
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            greeting.makeText(context, text, duration);

        }
    });
}
}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Hello/Goodbye</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="language">English</string>
<string name="greeting_msg">Greetings!</string>
<string name="goodbye_msg">Goodbye!</string>
<string name="greeting_toast">Hello!</string>
<string name="goodbye_toast">See you later!</string>

</resources>
```

My project is not finished by the way, but I cannot figure out why 
    `getString(R.string.greeting_msg);`

works, but

```
getString(R.string.greeting_toast);
```

will not work.  Every other string in my XML file can be referenced in my Java file except the last two, "greeting_toast" and "goodbye_toast".  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check whether you have imported proper R file in your code

Comment: You haven't initialized the context variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is your project containing error so that it cannot be built and R cannot be regenerated?
2. Make sure other strings.xml for different district / resolution also contain the R.string.greeting_toast.
3. Clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Thank you, simply cleaning the project got rid of the error, so irritating lol

Comment: Just like Mij said, your context is null. It should be work according to his changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it's work on your IDE, but my Android Studio shows some errors..

delete this line:

```
Toast greeting;
```

You have to get your context, because in your code context is null, I guess.

Then you have to, show your toast by adding .show()

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = getString(R.string.greeting_toast);
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();'
```

You can also short it to one line, like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.greeting_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```